# Sending variable inside ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I send a variable inside ggplot function, e.g. 'teststr' in following code:

```
tempfn = function(teststr){
    mydf = data.frame(a=1:10, b=rnorm(10))
    ggplot(mydf, aes(a,b))+ geom_point()+ 
           geom_text(aes(x=mean(a), y=mean(b), label=teststr))
}
```

Above function does not work and throws an error:

```
tempfn('check')
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'teststr' not found
```

Comment: You are trying to read a column "check", as `label=` is inside `aes`. But there is no "check" column in "df". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you mean `geom_text(aes(x=mean(a), y=mean(b)), label=teststr)` (note the label is outside the `aes()`)

Comment: Yes, "label=teststr" outside aes() works. Why don't you put it as an answer.